# React Router Toggle Basename

Tags: reactjs, react-router, browser-history

I'm having a `<BrowserRouter><App></BrowserRouter>` and am managing the current language with "context".

What I want to do is to toggle the URL when the language changes (I have no problem changing content).
The default URL is `site.com/...` and the English version is `site.com/en/...`.

I've been searching too much and can't seem to find a way that works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that you have a LanguageContext like this:

```html
<BrowserRouter>
 <LanguageProvider> 
  <App>
 <LanguageProvider>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Now let's build that LanguageContext:

**LanguageContext.js**

```js
const LanguageContext = React.createContext()
const LanguageProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [language, setLanguage] = useState("en");
    const history = useHistory();
    
    const changeLanguage = (newLanguage) => {
         setLanguage(newLanguage);
         
          const location = {
             pathname: `/${newLanguage}`,
         }
         history.push(location)
    }

    return (
     <Provider value={{changeLanguage}}>
        {children}
     </Provider>
    )
}

export {LanguageContext, LanguageProvider}
```

Now when you want to use this in your **MyComponent.js**

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
  
   const {changeLanguage} = useContext(LanguageContext);

   //let's say you handle a change through a select 
   
   const handleLanguageChange = (newLanguage) => {
      changeLanguage(newLanguage);
   }
   ....
}
```

Comment: Probably we want to call `history.push()` with the rest of the path like the current URL and only the language changed.